# Count the number of times each user moves to an area

Tags: r

```
user <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "b", "c")
time <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("12/01/22 21:05", format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M", tz="America/Chicago"), by="5 min", length.out=15)
area <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
df<-data.frame(user, time, area)
```

I want to create a new column to count the number of times each user moves to an area. In this example, user a didn't move, user b moved twice, user c moved once, and user d moved once. Also, I want to create a new column to identify whether or not a user moved to area 2 and stayed, move out of area 2 and stay in area 1, or move back and forth.

```
df <- df %>%group_by(user)%>%summarize(times_moved = n_distinct(area)-1)
df <- df[df$times_moved != 0, ]
```

This won't work since the question is related to time, user b moved twice.

Answer (score 2):

Number of times a user moved

```
> tapply(df$area,df$user,FUN=function(x){length(rle(x)$lengths)-1})
a b c d 
0 2 1 1
```

for a new column

```
> ave(df$area,df$user,FUN=function(x){length(rle(x)$lengths)-1})
 [1] 0 0 0 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 1
```